# How to use general http/https proxy with C++?

Tags: c++, proxy, mfc

Hi i am building a simple c++ program using http/https proxy.
I tried it to use the MFC CInternetSession class.
But it didn't work over many proxy servers.
So I tried it to use the libcurl.
It seems that working well.
But I am tired.
When i try to post the form to website. I saw the somethings as follows in smart sniffer.

```
[2016-01-13  1:49:16:973]
CONNECT m.pmang.com:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
Host: m.pmang.com
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

[2016-01-13  1:49:17:285]
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

[2016-01-13  1:49:17:300]
00000000  16 03 01 00 EA 01 00 00  E6 03 01 40 D2 75 C5 FF   ........ ...@.u..
```

My Code also received the "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established"
What is it?
What should i do for fix it?
Where is Http/Https proxy library working on general proxy servers(50.195.87.31:3128)?

Comment: 200 is the "everything went well" code. What is your problem with it?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I posted the form content. so I have to receive response html from remote server. for example "<html> </html>" But my code receive the "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established" from proxy server. How should i do?

Comment: `200` means _everything is OK, connection established_, no need to worry about this.

Comment: I am now using libcurl For example How should i write the code with libcurl?

Comment: Or hope to let me know about another way.

Answer (score 1):

According libcurl curl_easy_setopt [docs,](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) you can try this:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handler, CURLOPT_PROXY, proxy_server.c_str());
```

And if your proxy needs authentication:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handler, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, credentials.c_str());
```

Comment: Hi I wrote as follows CStringA proxyIp = m_proxyAddrA.Mid(0, off);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, proxyIp.GetString());
int port = atoi(m_proxyAddrA.Mid(off + 1, m_proxyAddrA.GetLength() - off - 1).GetString());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, port); Without proxy the code receive the response perfectly. I hope to know using proxy.